# Get Windows Back After Waking Up On 16.04 LTS

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, window

On my dual-monitor setup some windows get off screen after the sleep (suspend) mode. I have to manually <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to move them back. How can this be accomplished automatically after the sleep?

Comment: Have you tried checking  'additional drivers' for the latest video drivers?

Comment: End of Standard Support or End of Life Release? this question was certainly on-topic at the time it was written. Are we going to close all questions that are over five years old? Can I start flagging all old questions that refer to pre-18.04 releases or pre-20.04 flavor releases?

Answer (score 0):

Try disable the external monitor *before* going to sleep (if you think this complex procedure is worth it) in this way...
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149959/how-to-run-systemd-user-service-to-trigger-on-sleep-aka-suspend-hibernate
and use the xrandr command to disable (before going to sleep) and re-enable it (after returning from sleep)

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or F2...F6) to go into a text-mode vconsole, then Ctrl+Alt+F7 to switch back to graphics mode.

This forces the window system to re-draw everything, which often clears up graphical glitches such as what you describe.